# Use .bash_profile and .bashrc as one

Tags: bash

I have the following code in my .bash_profile:

```
  1 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"                                                                                           
  2                                                                                                                                                           
  3 export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"                                                                                                                               
  4 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm                                                                                        
  5 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

And the following in my .bashrc:

```
  1 # Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.                                                                         
  2 export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Is there an way to avoid one of the files? I mean, only use one as both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put following code in .bash_profile file. Basically source the .bashrc file in .bash_profile.

`source .bashrc`